# How to convert an ADP project under source control from Access 2000 to Access 2003?

Tags: ms-access, version-control

We have an ADP project created several years ago using Access 2000. This project is under source control (using the Access' standard MSSCCI-based add-in that integrates Access with SourceSafe).

Now we use Access 2003 to work with this project. Everything seems to be working okay, including integration with source control. However, when this ADP file is opened by Access 2003, it says that the project has "Access 2000" format.

Assuming that there are some good reasons to convert this ADP project from "Access 2000" format to "Access 2002-2003" format, the question is:

> How exactly can I perform such a conversion **without "losing" source control** (in particular, without losing all the source change history)?

Comment: Have you made a list of the things you will gain by converting? I would doubt that there are any improvements that would be worth the effort, particularly when you consider that ADPs are on the way out.

Comment: The key benefit we expected was better reliability of MS Access (esp. during development). The common sense suggested that Access 2003 should work better with "its own" format than with the old one. Before the conversion, Access had a tendency to "blow up" in developers' hands several times a week without any obvious reasons. After conversion - not a single failure. Coincidence? ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After certain amount of research across multiple information sources, I've found the following solution:

1. Open the ADP file (e.g. *MyProject.adp*) in MS Access, as usual.
2. Check out **everything**.
3. Use MS Access menu (*Tools >> Database Utilites >> Convert Database >> ...*) to convert the ADP file to "Access 2002-2003" format (e.g. using *MyProject_New.adp* as the name of the new file).
   (**IMPORTANT:** Answer "**NO**" to the Access' suggestion to remove the project from source control.)
4. Close the old ADP file and replace it by the new ADP file.
5. Change the Access' default file format (*Tools >> Options >> Advanced*) from "Access 2000" to "Access 2002-2003".
6. Open the now overwritten ADP file.
7. Check in **everything**.